Set up reverse proxy with Nginx to redirect traffic to specific port
I installed nginx on a recently installed Alma Linux 9 system. After starting the updates with sudo yum update -y I reviewed the initial configuration of nginx to be able to build a node application that runs on port 9999
nginx.config
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pidlogs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    includemime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfileon;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
listen80;
server_name  localhost;
#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
root   html;
index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404/404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root   html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    roothtml;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    includefastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen8000;
#    listensomename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#root   html;
#index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#root   html;
#index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

}

Just before the first server configuration I call the file that contains the reverse proxy.
include /etc/nginx/config.d/elchanchoganador.config

Following the steps in the documentation
server {
        listen      80;
        listen      [::]:80;
        #listen      443 ssl http2;  #NO SSL
        #listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  elchanchoganador.com www.elchanchoganador.com;

        #ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/rx-7.srv.world/fullchain1.pem";
        #ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/rx-7.srv.world/privkey1.pem";
        #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        #ssl_session_timeout  10m;

        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
        }
}

Reboot the system with:
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl reload nginx

It does not show errors when using nginx -t. But when I enter the domain I get the index page.
I want to be able to redirect everything I have on port 9999 to port 80, enter my domain without ports
http://www.example.com:9999/ node app
http://www.example.com/ => show node app content
my app is running on port 9999
